# AngularJS Inheritance between services

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm quite new to the angular world and have gotten into a problem where I want to implement a Interface(isch) behavior.

I have a "core" factory which is part of my domain and it looks like the following:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var domainModel = angular.module('my.model');
    domainModel.factory('IVehicle', function(Timezone) {
        function IVehicle(DTO) {
            this.Timezone = new Timezone();
            this.DTO = DTO;
            this.engine = DTO.engine;
            this.descriptor = this.getDescriptor();
        }

        IVehcile.prototype.getDescriptor = function() {
            if (this.type === -1) {
                return "this is a diesel vehicle";
            }
            else if (this.type === 0) {
                return "this is a fuel vehicle";
            }
            else {
                return "this is a environment vehicle";
            }
        };

        IVehicle.prototype.isGenericActivity = function() {
            return true;
        };

        return IVehicle;
    });
})();
```

Now I have a child module which "inherits" this factory:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

var models = angular.module('my.model');

models.factory('Car', function(Timezone, IVehicle) {
    function Car(CarDTO) {
        var me = this;



        IVehicle.call(me, CarDTO);

        this.additionalAttribute = CarDTO.additionalAttribute

        Car.prototype.hasParameters = function() {
        return this.parameters !== undefined && this.parameters.length !== 0;
    };

        Car.prototype = Object.create(ICar.prototype);

        Car.prototype.getDescriptor = function() {
        if (this.type === -1) {
            return "this is a diesel car";
        }
        else if (this.type === 0) {
            return "this is a fuel car";
        }
        else {
            return "this is a environment car";
        }
        };

        Car.prototype.isGenericActivity = function() {
            return true;
        };
}
    return Car;
    });
})();
```

When I run this I get an error on this.descriptor = this.getDescriptor() in IVehicle, as Car does not know about this.getDescriptor(). The fields (this.DTO, this.engine are set in the right way)

Is this the right way to go or is there anyway I can write the IVehicle as a real interface (as a contract on what to be implemented by it's child)? If this is the correct way, how do I handle function calls within the constructor of IVehicle?

Comment: All of your `Car` prototype assignment are inside the ```function Car()``` when outside for the vehicle one, also it's not clear what `ICar` is as it is never set. Shouldn't it be `IVehicle` instead of `ICar` for the `call` if you want to inherit things from `IVehicle`

Comment: check `IVehicle` for typos, not spelled the same each time